# Google App Engine Java small operation

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm planning a backend with Google App Engine application for Android. I would like some clarification as regards to Small operation. I did not understand if, for example:

```
Key key = ...
Entity entity = datastore.get(key)
```

Is this considered a small operation? And if it is not a small operation, can you give me an example of small operations in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing):

> Small datastore operations include calls to allocate datastore ids or
>   keys-only queries, and these operations are free.

So, `get` operation is a regular read, not a small operation. Here is an example of a small operation:

```
Query q = new Query("Photo").setKeysOnly();
```

When you run this query, it will result a bunch of small operations (depending on how many entities it finds).

Comment: So if the query returns n keys with the next iteration of n keys, you have n small operations right?

Comment: Yes. Since these operations are free, it's a great tool.